# I want to logout or revoke authentication in linkedin in javascript

Tags: oauth, token, linkedin-api

I have created my application in angularjs. In which I have attached openid with linkedin to fetch connections from linkedin account. I have gave functionality to add connections from multiple linkedin accounts so when from 1 account's connection fetched need to logout or revoke authentication from same webpage & again pop-up for login window. so it is possible to get connections from another account.

But my problem is that if I have already login in linkedin in another tab then in my application it is not asking me to login again. it is taking same login user again & again. so how can I overcome from this problem?

**Note : I am using REST APIs of linkedin to fetch connections & basic profiles & using Oauth2.0 for authentication.**

Comment: Are you using the "authorize: true" argument when you initialize the LinkedIn JS library?

Comment: I am using REST APIs. In my application javascript library is strictly prohibited. I have to use REST API. so how can I do it?

Comment: I don't understand why this is a problem.  If your user has granted access to your application previously, you usually don't want to keep bugging them with permission checks all the time until the original token they granted expires.

Comment: ya I can understand this but its requirement in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can only logout from linkedin on clear of cookies.

just destroy the cookies on login session will expired from browser.

Comment: you don't even really need to destory the cookies - just rename them if you don't want to lose them.